# dropdownlist selected value is not getting selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

what happening here is, whenever I am selecting a value from `dropdownlist`, the page is getting *postback* and it agains comes to **"--- Select ---"**.

I tried from the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302904/dropdownlist-selected-value-is-not-changing), but it didn't worked

```
if (DtMainA.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataTable DtGoodType = new DataTable();
    ObjPriDaAdp          = new OracleDataAdapter("select mkey, vehicle_no from XXCUS.XXGID_AUDIT_ENTRY where mkey= '" + Hid_MKey.Value + "'", ObjPriCon);
    ObjPriDaAdp.Fill(DtGoodType);

    if (DtGoodType.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        cmdVehicleNo.DataTextField = "vehicle_no";
        cmdVehicleNo.DataValueField = "mkey";
        cmdVehicleNo.DataSource = DtGoodType;
        cmdVehicleNo.DataBind();
        cmdVehicleNo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select ---", "0"));
   }
}
```

also see my aspx:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmdVehicleNo" runat="server" Style="width: 50%" AutoPostBack="true"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmdVehicleNo_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" >--- Select ---</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**UPDATE**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (ObjPriCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
        }
        if (hidAttachid.Value == "")
        {
            hidAttachid.Value = "0";
        }

        ObjPriCmd = new OracleCommand("Select count(MKEY)cntrow from XXCUS.XXGID_AUDIT_ENTRY", ObjPriCon);
        FunFillData();
        ObjPriCon.Close();
        fillProject();
        fillGoodType();
    }
}


protected void CmbProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "window.location.href='FrmCentral_Monitoring_Entry_OUT.aspx?userid=" + Hid_userid.Value + "';", true);
    if (CmbProject.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        DtCombo = FillComboBox("select mkey, vehicle_no from XXCUS.XXGID_AUDIT_ENTRY where time_out IS NULL and Project_id='" + CmbProject.SelectedValue + "'");

        cmdVehicleNo.DataTextField = "vehicle_no";
        cmdVehicleNo.DataValueField = "mkey";
        cmdVehicleNo.DataSource = DtCombo;
        cmdVehicleNo.DataBind();
        cmdVehicleNo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select ---", "0"));
        if (DtCombo.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            cmdVehicleNo.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
        DtCombo.Clear();
    }
    Funclear();
}
```

Comment: your aspx explicitly sets the **--- Select --** as selected by means of the `Selected="True"`

Comment: @Übercoder: after removing true from aspx. it still doesn't work as expected

Comment: Probably your problem is `postback`. Check this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544500/get-text-value-from-textbox-after-value-text-changed-server-side

Comment: @user2946329: yes my issue is with postback which is resetting value to default value. IN the link which you gaved, I m confused what shd I do ? do i need to call whole datatable again in the pageload

Comment: Strongly suspect you are missing the `!IsPostBack` condition on _Page_Load_. So it is rebinding the dropdown everytime.

Comment: @Übercoder - No that will not help cz when `cmdVehicleNo.DataBind();` is called that item will be overwritten already.

Comment: @RahulSingh: I have used that `(!IsPostBack`) property on `page_load` but still it is not working

Comment: @coder - How you have used? Can you show that?

Comment: @RahulSingh: updated the question. have a look

Comment: @coder - But where you are binding `cmdVehicleNo` dropdown? I can't see it in your Page_Load event code.

Comment: @RahulSingh: See the updated question now

Comment: place cmdVehicleNo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select ---", "0")); to the beginning of the if

Comment: @Creator: not working, still the same issue

Comment: just a question, does  <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" >--- Select ---</asp:ListItem> not select that value?

Comment: @Creator: actually while `selectingindexchanged` i commented one line i.e `cmdVehicleNo.SelectedValue = DtGoodType.Rows[0]["mkey"].ToString();` which was selecting value. but it was hapening on page_load,I wanted this on selecting manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very Obvious problem with your current code is that whenever you are selecting any item from the dropdownlist it is doing a *PostBack* and firing the `CmbProject_SelectedIndexChanged` event. In this event I don't know why you are again populating the dropdown. Ideally you should bind the dropdown only once in initial page load like this:-

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   BindDropDownList(); //Call this method
}

//Write a separate method to bind the dropdown
private void BindDropDownList()
{
    DataTable DtGoodType = new DataTable();
    ObjPriDaAdp = new OracleDataAdapter("select mkey, vehicle_no from XXCUS.XXGID_AUDIT_ENTRY where mkey= '" + Hid_MKey.Value + "'", ObjPriCon);
    ObjPriDaAdp.Fill(DtGoodType);

    if (DtGoodType.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
       cmdVehicleNo.DataTextField = "vehicle_no";
       cmdVehicleNo.DataValueField = "mkey";
       cmdVehicleNo.DataSource = DtGoodType;
       cmdVehicleNo.DataBind();
       cmdVehicleNo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select ---", "0"));
   }
}
```

Finally in the selected option change event you should only write the logic of what you want to do when user change the selection:-

```
protected void CmbProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do Stuffs
}
```

Comment: :- actually while `selectingindexchanged` i commented one line i.e `cmdVehicleNo.SelectedValue = DtGoodType.Rows[0]["mkey"].ToString();` which was selecting value. but it was hapening on page_load,I wanted this on selecting manually  Here is the code:- `if (Hid_MKey.Value != "0")
            {
                //cmdVehicleNo.SelectedValue = DtGoodType.Rows[0]["mkey"].ToString();
            }`

Comment: @coder - `CmbProject_SelectedIndexChanged` will be fired when user select some value in dropdown and you want to set something in this event? That's really weird. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: See, at `cmdVehicleNo` on `page_load`  i want default value which is working. but when I do `CmbProject_SelectedIndexChanged` i want first `cmdVehicleNo` to be default. after that I can select from `cmdVehicleNo`. selecting index change at that time is not working

Comment: @coder- So basically you want your user should select some value twice?

Comment: I want, whenever the dropdownlist is loaded with some values. first it should show the default value. and after some value is selected then the value should be their. currently the value is not getting selected.

Comment: currently, even after selecting the default value, it again goes to some another value and gets sets. :(

Comment: i got that. i just needed to change the condition. by changing it, it worked accordingly